# cmd - Accessing Folder with Environment Variable Name

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I'm just curious about this:

It's possible to create a Folder, in Windows Explorer, with the same Name as an Environment Variable (like `%ProgramData%`).

The same procedure in CMD.exe with `mkdir` prevents this and if i try to access this folder, i always get re-directed to the Environment Variable.

But is there any known way to access this kind of Folder with the command-line?

Are there any escape parameters for this, to prevent resolving the variable?

Comment: Relevant: [In Windows Explorer, why can we create a folder or file with the percent (%) symbol, if the percent symbol is used for existing variables?](https://superuser.com/q/1096208)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing the directory (via `cd`), you could use the console's character replacement (aka [wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)), and replace one of (or both) the percent signs with a question mark.  e.g.:

- `cd ?ProgramData%`
- `cd %ProgramData?`
- `cd ?ProgramData?`

Alternatively, and for use with other commands like `rename`, `md` and such, you can escape the percentage with a caret (`^`).  e.g:

- `md ^%ProgramData^%`

Comment: This works, so far. But for `mkdir` and `rename`, this is no solution. :/

Comment: I assumed that when you asked about "Accessing" the folder, that you meant you wanted to navigate into the folder.

Comment: No problem; it was an interesting question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mkdir with

```
mkdir "%test%"
```

and then navigate to it with

```
cd "%test%"
```

Also works with rename

Comment: Is `%test%` a resolvable `Environment Variable` on your System?

Comment: oh, good question.  I'll set it and try that again.

Comment: Interesting.  test is equal to value.  When I mkdir "%test%" I get a directory  named value.  Should have seen that coming. hehe